# Объединение двух массивов php

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет, уже пару часов сижу и мой мозг кипит.
Подскажите как можно реализовать такой способ объединения массивов

Имеется

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Au revoir
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Rebel_(228)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => НяФФфФФка
        )

)

нужно обединить с

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
        )

)

Что б в итоге получить

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Au revoir
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Rebel_(228)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => НяФФфФФка
            [connected] => TRUE
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [name] => 
            [connected] => TRUE
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr2 as $connectedId) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($arr1 as &$person) {
        if (isset($person['id']) && $person['id'] === $connectedId['id']) {
            $person['connected'] = true;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $arr1[] = array('id' => $connectedId['id'], 'connected' => true);
    }
}
```

А если бы вместо ключей массива использовались айдишники, то всего этого геморроя не было бы.

Comment: [32] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [connected] => 1
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [connected] => 1
        )


Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in  if ($person['id'] === $connectedId['id']) {


Убейте меня

Comment: и вот откуда [id] => 7 всегда 7 я не понимаю :/

Comment: @wwwplaton, похоже на то, что структура немного другая на самом деле. А сcontinue я там напутал, кажется, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Все равно в if на $connectedId['id'] ругается

Comment: Fike извиняюсь это я накосячил, последний вариант работает на урааа. 
Спасибо большое, очередной раз помог :)))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Не совсем идет, он просто складывает. А мне сравнить и обработать нудно.

Answer (score -2):

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```